# How to fix children alignment in this forest?

Tags: align, forest

I am trying to align the Branches 1 and 2 of this forest with the vertical lines under Subtitles 1 and 2, but I haven't been able to do it so far. Do you know how to do this?.

[image: My forest diagram]

The diagram was made with this code.
In the preamble:

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\makeatletter
\csdef{forest@compute@node@boundary@rounded rectangle}{%
  \forest@mt{east}%
  \forest@lt{north east}%
  \forest@lt{north}%
  \forest@lt{north west}%
  \forest@lt{west}%
  \forest@lt{south west}%
  \forest@lt{south}%
  \forest@lt{south east}%
  \forest@lt{east}%
}
\makeatother
```

and in the document:

```
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
t1/.style={style={draw=black,text height=2.3ex,text depth=.85ex},rounded corners},
t2/.style={style={draw=black,text height=4.5ex,text depth=3ex},rounded corners},
t3/.style={style={draw=black,text height=6.6ex,text depth=5.0ex},rounded corners},
for tree={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-8pt)-| (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
}
[Title, s sep=8mm,t1
 [Subtitle 1, s sep=8mm,t1
  [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t3
   [Branch 1, s sep=8mm,t1
    [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
   ]
   [Branch 2, s sep=8mm,t1
    [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
   ]
  ]
 ]
 [Subtitle 2, s sep=8mm,t1
  [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Including both the preamble and the document worked fine, but note that it is customary to post them together as a part of a complete, compilable document — what is called MWE (minimal working example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *approximate* solution is very simple: add `calign=1` to the triple-bullet node containing the "Branches". This key aligns the node with the first (because `1`) child; in our case, it will vertically align "Branch 1" to the triple-bullet node (and thus "Subtitle 1"). This would work perfectly if the  "Subtitle" nodes were of the same width as the "Branch" nodes. As this is not the case, "Branch 2" turns out a bit misaligned, so we need to develop another solution.

The position of the child relative to the parent is stored in `s` (given the growth direction of our tree, this later translates to the `x` coordinate). So the idea is to copy `s` from the "Subtitle" nodes to the "Branch" nodes — this will transfer the "horizontal distances" between "Subtitles" to the "Branches" — and then subtract (`s-`) the `s` of "Subtitle 1" from the `s` of all the "Branches" — this will make `s` of "Branch 1" zero, aligning it under the parent, while all the other "Branch" nodes will get aligned with their corresponding "Subtitle" nodes.

Let's do this manually first. The relevant code can be found in `before computing xy` in "Branch 1" and "Branch 2".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\makeatletter
\csdef{forest@compute@node@boundary@rounded rectangle}{%
  \forest@mt{east}%
  \forest@lt{north east}%
  \forest@lt{north}%
  \forest@lt{north west}%
  \forest@lt{west}%
  \forest@lt{south west}%
  \forest@lt{south}%
  \forest@lt{south east}%
  \forest@lt{east}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    t1/.style={style={draw=black,text height=2.3ex,text depth=.85ex},rounded corners},
    t2/.style={style={draw=black,text height=4.5ex,text depth=3ex},rounded corners},
    t3/.style={style={draw=black,text height=6.6ex,text depth=5.0ex},rounded corners},
    for tree={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-8pt)-| (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
    }
    [Title, s sep=8mm,t1
      [Subtitle 1, s sep=8mm,t1
        [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t3,
          [Branch 1, s sep=8mm,t1,
            before computing xy={s/.option={!r1.s}, s-/.option={!r1.s}},
            [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
          ]
          [Branch 2, s sep=8mm,t1,
            before computing xy={s/.option={!r2.s}, s-/.option={!r1.s}},
            [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Subtitle 2, s sep=8mm,t1
        [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

`before computing xy` is a *temporal propagator* delaying the execution of the key to a moment when the tree is already packed (i.e. Forest has determined where to put each node and stored this decision in `s` and `l` of the nodes) but before the tree-layout is transferred into the paper-coordinates `x` and `y`.

`.option` is a *key handler* telling Forest that the given value should be interpreted as an option name, and a relative option name at that. Read `!r1.s` as follows: `!` means "we'll go for a walk"; `r` = let's go to the root node; `1` = let's go to the first child; the dot separates the relative node name from the option name; `s` is the option we want to grab. So, `s/.option={!r1.s}` instructs Forest so take option `s` of the first child of the root node and store it in option `s` of the current node.

Of course, the manual approach is cumbersome to use when we have many nodes to take care of. Below, we adjust option `s` of all the "Branches" at once. The relevant code can again be found inside `before computing xy`, but now this temporal propagator occurs in the triple-bullet node, which is the parent of the "Branches".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\makeatletter
\csdef{forest@compute@node@boundary@rounded rectangle}{%
  \forest@mt{east}%
  \forest@lt{north east}%
  \forest@lt{north}%
  \forest@lt{north west}%
  \forest@lt{west}%
  \forest@lt{south west}%
  \forest@lt{south}%
  \forest@lt{south east}%
  \forest@lt{east}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    t1/.style={style={draw=black,text height=2.3ex,text depth=.85ex},rounded corners},
    t2/.style={style={draw=black,text height=4.5ex,text depth=3ex},rounded corners},
    t3/.style={style={draw=black,text height=6.6ex,text depth=5.0ex},rounded corners},
    for tree={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-8pt)-| (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
    }
    [Title, s sep=8mm,t1
      [Subtitle 1, s sep=8mm,t1
        [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t3,
          before computing xy={
            for children={
              s/.process=Ow+O{n}{!r#1.s},
              s-/.option={!r1.s},
            },
          },
          [Branch 1, s sep=8mm,t1,
            [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
          ]
          [Branch 2, s sep=8mm,t1,
            [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Subtitle 2, s sep=8mm,t1
        [$\begin{array}{l} \bullet \\ \bullet \end{array}$, s sep=8mm,t2]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The spatial propagator `for children` is self-explanatory: it uses the given options with each child. The second, `s-`, line within `for children` is also familiar: it will subtract the `s` of the first child of the root from the  `s` of the current node. The first line, invoking *argument processor* with `.process`, requires an explanation — but to really understand how it works, you will also want to consult manual section 3.13.

The value of `.process` consists of two parts: the instructions (`OwO`) and the arguments (`{n}{!r#1.s}`).

- The first instruction, `O`, tells forest to look up an option. Which option? Its name is given in the first argument: `n`, the option holding the child number of the node ("Branch 1" and "Subtitle 1" have `n=1`; "Branch 2" and "Subtitle 2" have `n=2`). The result (the value of `n` at the current node) then becomes the first *processed* argument.
- The second instruction is `w`: wrap the first remaining argument around the last processed argument. In our case, the first remaining argument is `!r#1.s`. It is treated as a macro definition, and `#1` is replaced with the last processed argument. Let's say we're at "Branch 2": then the result of this instruction is that `!r2.s` becomes the last processed argument.
- Instruction `+` makes the last processed argument become the first remaining argument.
- `O` again looks up an option named in the first remaining argument; in our case, `!r2.s`.  We already know what this is: the `s` of the second child of the root, i.e. the `s` of "Subtitle 2". This value then becomes the last processed argument.
- There are no more instructions, so the last processed argument, i.e. the `s` of "Subtitle 2", is stored in the `s` of the current node (because `s/.process`). (In general, all the processed arguments plus the remaining arguments are passed to the calling option.)

In short, short but complicated (at least until you get used to it:).

Comment: This is incredible, thank you so much. A very in-depth explanation to study and learn from it. :) Also, thanks for your comments on the MWE issue when posting.

Comment: That's the idea ;-)